# Selecting an item from AutoComplete suggestion list raises KeyDown-event with ENTER key

Tags: c#, autocomplete, textbox, onkeydown

In Winforms I have a textbox with AutoCompleteMode set to SuggestAppend and a AutoCompleteCustomSource set. When the user types some letters the suggestion list is shown. If an item of this list is selected by clicking it with the mouse, the KeyDown-event of the form containing the textbox is raised for the ENTER key.

Is there any possibility to NOT raise this event when selecting a suggested item with the mouse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The AutoComplete feature has a couple of quirks that were inherited from its original designed use, the address box of Internet Explorer.  This includes emitting the Enter key when you click on an item in the list.  Pressing Enter in the address box of IE makes it navigate to the entered URL.

There isn't anything you can do about that, the native interface (IAutoComplete2) has very few options to configure the way it works.  It pokes the keystrokes into the text box by faking Windows messages.  Which is one way you can tell the difference, the actual key won't be down.  Something you can check by pinvoking GetKeyState(), like this:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter && GetKeyState(Keys.Enter) < 0) {
            Console.WriteLine("Really down");
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern short GetKeyState(Keys key);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this is a solution that works! I've already recognized that there are some drawbacks in using the AutoComplete-feature. Maybe it would be better at all to write a custom AutoComplete textbox.

Comment: Very useful answer. Too bad MS didn't provide some way to determine that an autocomplete suggestion was used. I would like to ignore the Enter key if they highlight a suggestion and press enter as well. I even looked to see if the stack traces were different, but they are identical. Perhaps there is a way if you track every possible way to capture input (keyboard, paste, others?) and assume autocomplete if nothing else was entered. But I think I am OK with not capturing every possible situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch keydown keys:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
    //Do nothing or something
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that pressing the enter key in the textbox should activate some other action but selecting just an item should not do that. So I would need to find out in the KeyDown-handler in your example if the event was raised by pressing the enter key manually or if it was raised by selecting an item.

Comment: The KeyDown event fires the e.KeyCode = 13 (ENTER) when the user presses Enter or Double Clicks on an item in the list. I don't think you can handle the difference between the 'enter' and the click event, because they are set to fire the same event. The only way you can go around easily is to activate 'other actions' with a button