# datagridview textbox control autocomplete - handle item not in list

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox

I have this code to set one of my textbox columns in a datagridview to autocomplete:

```
private void datagridWorkorderPartItems_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.datagridWorkorderPartItems.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            e.Control.KeyPress += Control_KeyPress;
            //  e.Control.KeyDown += Control_KeyDown;
        }
        else if (this.datagridWorkorderPartItems.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            e.Control.KeyPress += Control_PriceKeypress;
        }
        else
        {

        }

        //make the part number column in the data grid view auto complete, and if the part is not in the list, need to add
        TextBox textPart = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (this.datagridWorkorderPartItems.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 3 && textPart != null)
            {
            textPart.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            textPart.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            Parts part = new Parts();
            DataTable partdata = new DataTable();
            partdata = part.LoadPartTable();
            foreach (DataRow row in partdata.Rows)
                {
                textPart.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(row["PartNumber"].ToString());
                }
            }
        else if (this.datagridWorkorderPartItems.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex != 3 && textPart != null)
            {
            textPart.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;
            }
    }
```

It works great but now I would like to handle an item that is typed in that does not match any item in the underlying list. It would allow free text entry but ask the user if they want to save the new item.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

See the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515561/how-can-i-dynamically-change-auto-complete-entries-in-a-c-sharp-combobox-or-text) SO question.

I would not recommend to ask user whether to save the new item into the `AutoCompleteCustomSource`. Rather it should be transparent to the user. I assume that you are updating the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` every time the editing control is attached with the data from `part.LoadPartTable`. If the `PartTable` is updated with the user entered data then next time when you set the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` from `PartTable`, the user entered data will be automatically added to `AutoCompleteCustomSource` .

Comment: My intention is to allow a user to type a part number into the text box in the data grid view, and if the part does not exist, then allow them to enter it with an option of adding it to the parts list that is the source for auto complete. I don't want it to be transparent to the user. So it should function as auto complete but also as free text. The auto complete code does not seem to allow typing a value that does not match the list.

Comment: @Ryan - I checked in a sample program. It allows me to enter text which are not in the auto complete list.

Comment: I added more code to show the entire event that the code is in. It seems that after I type in and select a matching item in the text box, it does not allow me backspace...I must have something wrong.

Comment: I think I understand your problem. Once you select any item in the list, the control emits enter(check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055883/selecting-an-item-from-autocomplete-suggestion-list-raises-keydown-event-with-en) key and ends the edit operation of the cell. Once the edit operation ends, the editing control is detached and your backspace key is handled by datagridview not the editing control which in your case the textbox.

Comment: ok, interesting, so do i need to handle the backspace as the editing control? Like with a keypress?

Comment: No you have to bring the cell back in edit mode. I tried capturing the KeyDown for both `datagridview` and `textbox` and check for `Enter` key in a sample program. But it seems the `datagridview` internally handles the `Enter` key and ends the editing.