# Textbox autocomplete source

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

With a combobox in **winforms** I am able to add items that can be a custom class and what is shown in the combo is the result of the `ToString()` method of that class

I would ideally like to have similar behaviour with the autocomplete of a TextBox, but it seems to me that you must provide an `AutoCompleteStringCollection` for this. Is anyone aware of a way I can associate an `int` value with each string in the `AutoCompleteSource` for the textbox?

Edit - I cannot simply look up for the `int` based upon the selected string because they may be strings in the textbox autocomplete that are the same

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Um, are you sure of this design? If the strings can be the same, how will a user know the difference you want to make with the numbers??

Comment: That has occurred to me but I can't think of anything better at this moment. Basically this is a list of operators that perform jobs and the user must choose one from the list. Any better ideas would be welcome :)

Comment: Well, if several operators have the same name, you will have to add something to their name to help users discern them anyway, right?

Comment: I suppose I probably would have to. It seems my problem is more of a design problem rather than a technical one

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution; a bit of a hack, but it might help you out.

If you add the numbers to the string in a way that is both acceptable to the users and easily reconizable/removeable you can test for it in the KeyUp event, extract the index and clean up the Text.

So a string could look like this

```
New York City          <<01>>
```

and you wouldn't have much trouble to get at the index and removing the markup..

Look at [this answer by Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055883/selecting-an-item-from-autocomplete-suggestion-list-raises-keydown-event-with-en) who deals with detecting the (fake) KeyDown that gets fired. You can adapt this to deal with the KeyUp so you won't interfere with the normal editing.

But to reiterate, this makes no sense, if for the choice of the user the strings have a meaning and not their, say, position..